# Angularjs: how to set default value of input type number with out controller function

Tags: angularjs

When I try to solve this I found `ng-init` solution but it is also not working, it shows the following error.

> Error: [ngModel:numfmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/ngModel/numfmt?p0=pd.ava_qty
>
> Stack trace:

Here is my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="pd in pres_data">
                <td>{{pd.name}}</td>
                <td>{{pd.pur_qty}}</td>
                <td>{{pd.ava_qty}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="order_qty" ng-init="order_qty='pd.ava_qty'"  max="{{pd.ava_qty}}" min="0" />
```

Comment: remove `'` from `"order_qty='pd.ava_qty'"`.

Comment: It not working same error is occur and value is not showing

Comment: what is the value of `pd.ava_qty` and datatype ??

Answer (score 0):

You have define the input to `type="number"` but setting the value to text

`ng-init="order_qty='pd.ava_qty'"`

Try it like this

```
ng-init="order_qty=pd.ava_qty"
```

Comment: It not working same error is occur and value is not showing

Comment: This is pres_data json
0 {…}
product_id LIiICBoqvtHDvqZQjsCY5Dk-ARHCJLTeSVkGMzXz_Zg
name Aceclofenac 100 mg
pur_qty 10
ava_qty 12
1 {…}
product_id OqG94GafY-DRXARgWFdNH9vxhxP4tW0K75YEfEvzwzg
name Asprin 150 mg
pur_qty 5
ava_qty 6

Answer (score 0):

you error says it expects pd.ava_qty to be a number

so in your `ng-init` you can have `pd.ava_qty = 10` or any number you want as your default

```
<tr ng-repeat="pd in pres_data">
            <td>{{pd.name}}</td>
            <td>{{pd.pur_qty}}</td>
            <td>{{pd.ava_qty}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="order_qty" ng-init="pd.ava_qty = 10;order_qty=pd.ava_qty"  max="{{pd.ava_qty}}" min="0" />
```

Comment: Thanx sir it working but in place of 10 how can i set dynamic value.
I recheck my code and pd.ava_qty contain(15,5,50). how i convert pd.ava_qty to number

Comment: Simply change the 10 to a variable name you have already initialized with a numeric value. Don't forget to mark as answer :)

Comment: Sir when i try this code it not working again 
ng-init="pd.ava_qty = pd.ava_qty;order_qty=pd.ava_qty" but when i put 10 in place of pd.ava_qty its work fine. Please help me sir ... please

Comment: It won't work cos you have not yet set any value for `pd.ava_qty` what do you want to set the default value as?

Comment: Sri pd.ava_qty value is coming from ng-repeat loop with JSON Here is JSON data
0 {…} product_id LIiICBoqvtHDvqZQjsCY5Dk-ARHCJLTeSVkGMzXz_Zg name Aceclofenac 100 mg pur_qty 10 ava_qty 12 
1 {…} product_id OqG94GafY-DRXARgWFdNH9vxhxP4tW0K75YEfEvzwzg name Asprin 150 mg pur_qty 5 ava_qty 6

Comment: well I think something is wrong with your JSON and `pd.ava_qty` is not coming in as a number

Comment: Thanx sir now i got the error. In JSON ava_qty is string format